# Nested HashMaps and Declaration

Tags: java, dictionary, nested, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to experiment with `Map`s and I have this doubt:

```
Map<String, Object> input = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
String operator = "in";
String argument = "foo";
String field = "AvailabilityStatus";
Map<String, Object> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
innerMap.put(operator, argument);
input.put(field, innerMap);
```

The function call for the above code is

```
String output = FunctionA(input);
```

Seems to work fine but changing the input to:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> input = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();
```

doesn't let me call the function the same way. The `functionA` is:

```
public static String FunctionA(Map<String, Object> filters) throws Throwable {
//logic goes here
}
```

Aren't the two statements essentially trying to do the same thing?

Comment: _doesn't let me call the function the same way_ please elaborate

Comment: as in, why can't I do A nested Map with a Map both implementing a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: `Map<String, Object>` and `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` are not the same thing. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: There's a red error which pops up saying both are of incompatible types. Why si it diff when I change it to LinkedHashMap for the nested Map but doesn't show me an error while I do it separately as an innerMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you could make the FunctionA method like this:

```
public static String FunctionA(Map<String, ? extends Object> filters) throws Throwable{
//logic goes here
}
```

Doing this will be happy then!

```
FunctionA(new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>());
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` is not a subtype of `Map<String, Object>`, even though `Map<String, Object>`is a subtype of `Object`.

Indeed, uou can store whatever object you want in the latter, whereas you can only store `Map<String, Object>` instances in the former. That's why the compiler doesn't let you pass a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` to a method taking a `Map<String, Object>` as argument.

If it let you do that, the method could store Strings, Integers or Bananas into the map, which would thus ruin the type-safety of the map, supposed to only contain instances of `Map<String, Object>`.